# How can I delete a shortcut from the Start Menu Recently Used Programs section?

Tags: windows-7

How can I delete a shortcut (just the one) from the Start Menu Recently Used Programs section in Windows 7?  Ideally I'd like to replace it with another. I'll need to do this via a script, bat file or GPO as I have over 2000 users.

Thanks
Steven

Comment: What about disabling the start menu MRU in the registry, or do your users actually use this list?

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in the registry ROT13'd (unless it's disabled by adding a specific registry key) under: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist\`. It's not so easy to do a replacement due to how much information is stored here.